# -Windowstyle Hidden not working on Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

So I know pretty much nothing about PowerShell but I've been trying to slowly learn.

The end goal is to have PowerShell open up a NOT visible instance of Internet Explorer that navigates to 'Google.com' with the parameters

-noframemerging -private

So far

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' 'google.com -noframemerging -private'
```

works in creating an IE but it is NOT hidden.

I also tried another piece of code

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' 'google.com -noframemerging -private'
```

but the IE window is still visible. How can I fix this?

And `-WindowStyle Minimized` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden iexplore.exe 
              -ArgumentList "google.com -noframemerging -private"
```

Comment: Is this just another piece of code you tried out? Or is this working for you? Please edit your answer and describe whats the purpose of your post.